# Retrieving IBM Cloud Object Storage S3 pricing via API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is there any way that I can retrieve "IBM Cloud Object Storage - S3" pricing figures through some API calls?

The pricing figures that I am looking to retrieve through API are highlighted in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/697Yd.png) screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this request using REST ful:

```
https://$USERID:$APIKEY8@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/206/getObjectStorageDatacenters
```

Then you need to look for all the items whose long description proiperty contains "Cleversafe"

e.g.

[image]

this is the value for this attribute that you are going to get using the request above:

```
 {
                "currentPriceFlag": null,
                "hourlyRecurringFee": "0",
                "id": 177743,
                "itemId": 8179,
                "laborFee": "0",
                "locationGroupId": null,
                "onSaleFlag": null,
                "oneTimeFee": "0",
                "quantity": null,
                "recurringFee": "0",
                "setupFee": "0",
                "sort": 0,
                "usageRate": ".03",
                "item": {
                    "capacity": "0",
                    "description": "Standard Cross Region",
                    "id": 8179,
                    "itemTaxCategoryId": 166,
                    "keyName": "STANDARD_CROSS_REGION",
                    "longDescription": "Standard Cross Region - CLEVERSAFE",
                    "softwareDescriptionId": null,
                    "units": "GIGABYTE",
                    "upgradeItemId": null,
                    "itemCategory": {
                        "categoryCode": "object_storage_service",
                        "id": 812,
                        "name": "Object Storage Service",
                        "quantityLimit": 0
                    }
                }
            },
```

As you can see in the description it says "Standard Cross Region" the usageRate says ".03" and the units say "GYGABYTE" . You just need to look for the other vaules in the response

Regards